# PHP file permissions

Tags: php, file, file-permissions

How can I **set permissions of a file** to let a **PHP program read and write** but **not be read by** the public.  When I set read permissions **it denies PHP to the files**.

Comment: Is this PHP program being invoked via a web server like Apache? Or is it a command line script run by the user that owns the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- change ownership to the apache user (either apache, www-date or http, depending on OS).
- modify permission, `chmod 700` or `chmod 750`

Comment: `600` / `640`, unless one is working with executable files... (sorry, pet peeve of mine that everyone seems to force all their files executable, makes admin tasks like _finding_ executables a hell...)

Comment: I think you meant `www-data` rather than `www-date`

Comment: double doh ... yea i meant read/write w/ no execute. www-date if he's using debian.

Comment: How do I do this - change ownership to the apache user (either apache, www-date or http, depending on OS).

Comment: You'll need access to the console either via ssh or directly logged in. Do you have such access?

Comment: umm, so ssh is shell (command prompt), what do I use? `chown file.txt "apache"` or something like that

Comment: yes, you'll need to figure out which user owns the apache process.